# FFmpeg video overlay function not working

Tags: c, flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I am simply trying to get a watermarked video from the Flutter FFmpeg package and cannot seem to get it to work. Right now, I am downloading the video from Firebase, storing it in cache, overlaying a watermark image using the Flutter FFmpeg Kit package. The original video file, image file, and output file are being created properly.

However, the overlay function is not working properly. How can I use the `FFmpegKit.execute` function string? I am not seeing any obvious errors in the function, but it isn't working properly. I tried writing as a new File and `asBytes` but neither worked.

Edit: I want to take the `originalVideo` and overlay it with the `watermark` image with the expected outcome being a new file that contains the new overlayed video. Not concerned with where the overlay is yet.

Pubspec.yaml

```
ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^4.5.1
```

The function is:

```
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/ffmpeg_kit.dart';

Future<File> waterMarkVideo(String videoPath, String watermarkPath) async {
    //these calls are to load the video into temporary directory
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(videoPath));
    final originalVideo = File ('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/video.mp4');
    await originalVideo.create(recursive: true);
    await originalVideo.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    print('video path' + originalVideo.path);

    //this grabs the watermark image from assets and decodes it
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load(watermarkPath);
    final watermark = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/image.png');
    await watermark.create(recursive: true);
    await watermark.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
    print('watermark path' + watermark.path);

    //this creates temporary directory for new watermarked video
    var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final newVideoPath = '${tempDir.path}/${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}result.mp4';
    final videoFile = await File(newVideoPath).create();

//overlaying video using FFmpegkit where I need some help
    await FFmpegKit.executeAsync("-i $originalVideo -i $watermark -filter_complex 'overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2' $videoFile")
    .then((session) async {
      final state = FFmpegKitConfig.sessionStateToString(await session.getState());
      final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
      final failStackTrace = await session.getFailStackTrace();
      final output = await session.getOutput();
      print('FFmpeg process exited with state ${state} and rs ${returnCode}.If failed ${failStackTrace}');
      print('Last output $output');
    } );
    print('new video path' + newVideoPath);
    Uint8List videoByteData = await videoFile.readAsBytes();
    return videoFile.writeAsBytes(videoByteData);
}
```

The output for the function above is

```
flutter: video path/Users/dennisashford/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FBFB4D51-EC31-47DF-8FE0-66B114806EA4/data/Containers/Data/Application/0EA3BB35-D364-4B98-A104-15CDB17AAD54/Library/Caches/video.mp4
flutter: watermark path/Users/dennisashford/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FBFB4D51-EC31-47DF-8FE0-66B114806EA4/data/Containers/Data/Application/0EA3BB35-D364-4B98-A104-15CDB17AAD54/Library/Caches/image.png
ffmpeg version v4.5-dev-3393-g30322ebe3c Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
  configuration: --cross-prefix=x86_64-ios-darwin- --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/apple-ios-x86_64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=x86_64 --cpu=x86_64 --target-os=darwin --disable-neon --disable-asm --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='clang -arch x86_64 -target x86_64-apple-ios12.1-simulator -march=x86-64 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -m64 -DFFMPEG_KIT_X86_64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -DIOS -DFFMPEG_KIT_BUILD_DATE=20220114 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk -O2 -mios-simulator-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --nm=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm --extra-ldflags='-mios-simulator-version-min=12.1' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --disable-static --install-name-dir='@rpath' --enable-pthreads --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --disable-sdl2 --disable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --disable-outdev=audiotoolbox --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv --disable-coreimage --disable-appkit --disable-opencl --disable-opengl
  libavutil      57. 13.100 / 57. 13.100
  libavcodec     59. 15.102 / 59. 15.102
  libavformat    59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
  libavdevice    59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavfilter     8. 21.100 /  8. 21.100
  libswscale      6.  1.102 /  6.  1.102
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
File:: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:File:?
flutter: FFmpeg process exited with state RUNNING and rs 1.If failed null
flutter: Last output ffmpeg version v4.5-dev-3393-g30322ebe3c Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
flutter:   built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
flutter:   configuration: --cross-prefix=x86_64-ios-darwin- --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/apple-ios-x86_64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=x86_64 --cpu=x86_64 --target-os=darwin --disable-neon --disable-asm --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='clang -arch x86_64 -target x86_64-apple-ios12.1-simulator -march=x86-64 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -m64 -DFFMPEG_KIT_X86_64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -DIOS -DFFMPEG_KIT_BUILD_DATE=20220114 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk -O2 -mios-simulator-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --nm=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm --extra-ldflags='-mios-simulator-version-min=12.1' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --disable-static --install-name-dir='@rpath' --enable-pthreads --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --disable-sdl2 --disable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --disable-outdev=audiotoolbox --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv --disable-coreimage --disable-appkit --disable-opencl --disable-opengl
flutter:   libavutil      57. 13.100 / 57. 13.100
flutter:   libavcodec     59. 15.102 / 59. 15.102
flutter:   libavformat    59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
flutter:   libavdevice    59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
flutter:   libavfilter     8. 21.100 /  8. 21.100
flutter:   libswscale      6.  1.102 /  6.  1.102
flutter:   libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
flutter: File:: Protocol not found
flutter: Did you mean file:File:?
flutter: 
flutter: new video path/Users/dennisashford/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FBFB4D51-EC31-47DF-8FE0-66B114806EA4/data/Containers/Data/Application/0EA3BB35-D364-4B98-A104-15CDB17AAD54/Library/Caches/1661892011213545result.mp4
```

**Update:** So I built the code on a physical device and was able to get a little more information for what may be the problem. The error may be coming from

```
File:: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:File:?
```

Complete logs from the physical device are given below

```
flutter: video path/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/70EA92CD-DF5D-440E-BBE1-C130BC7F0CC7/Library/Caches/video.mp4
flutter: watermark path/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/70EA92CD-DF5D-440E-BBE1-C130BC7F0CC7/Library/Caches/image.png
ffmpeg version v4.5-dev-3393-g30322ebe3c Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
  configuration: --cross-prefix=arm64-ios-darwin- --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/apple-ios-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8 --target-os=darwin --enable-neon --enable-asm --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='/Users/taner/Projects/ffmpeg-kit/.tmp/gas-preprocessor.pl -arch aarch64 -- clang -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-ios12.1 -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=generic -DFFMPEG_KIT_ARM64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -fembed-bitcode -DIOS -DFFMPEG_KIT_BUILD_DATE=20220114 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk -Oz -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --nm=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm --extra-ldflags='-miphoneos-version-min=12.1' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --disable-static --install-name-dir='@rpath' --enable-pthreads --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --disable-sdl2 --disable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --disable-outdev=audiotoolbox --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv --disable-coreimage --disable-appkit --disable-opencl --disable-opengl
  libavutil      57. 13.100 / 57. 13.100
  libavcodec     59. 15.102 / 59. 15.102
  libavformat    59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
  libavdevice    59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavfilter     8. 21.100 /  8. 21.100
  libswscale      6.  1.102 /  6.  1.102
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
File:: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:File:?
flutter: FFmpeg process exited with state RUNNING and rs 1.If failed null
flutter: Last output ffmpeg version v4.5-dev-3393-g30322ebe3c Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
  configuration: --cross-prefix=arm64-ios-darwin- --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/apple-ios-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8 --target-os=darwin --enable-neon --enable-asm --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='/Users/taner/Projects/ffmpeg-kit/.tmp/gas-preprocessor.pl -arch aarch64 -- clang -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-ios12.1 -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=generic -DFFMPEG_KIT_ARM64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -fembed-bitcode -DIOS -DFFMPEG_KIT_BUILD_DATE=20220114 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk -Oz -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --nm=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm --extra-ldflags='-miphoneos-version-min=12.1' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --disable-static --install-name-dir='@rpath' --enable-pthreads --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --disable-sdl2 --disable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --disable-outdev=audiotoolbox --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv --disable-coreimage --disable-appkit --disable-opencl --disable-opengl
  libavutil      57. 13.100 / 57. 13.100
  libavcodec     59. 15.102 / 59. 15.102
  libavformat    59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
  libavdevice    59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavfilter     8. 21.100 /  8. 21.100
  libswscale      6.  1.102 /  6.  1.102
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
File:: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:File:?
flutter: new video path/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/70EA92CD-DF5D-440E-BBE1-C130BC7F0CC7/Library/Caches/1661891272856433result.mp4
```

**Update #2** after a lot of help from @kesh below, this function was actually able to overlay the image on the video.

```
await FFmpegKit.executeAsync('-i $videoPath -i ${watermark.path} -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -y ${videoFile.path}')
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome of the overlay function? Hard to tell what is "proper" without knowing that

Comment: I want to take the `originalVideo` and overlay it with the `watermark` image with the expected outcome being a new file that contains that new overlayed video. Not concerned with where the overlay is yet. Does that help? Pretty new to coding, so apologies if not.

Comment: (Should've asked this above but...) and what are you getting now? Also, what are the dimensions of the 2 video frames?

Comment: @kesh currently nothing is being written to the new `videoFile` being created. So I believe the `ffmpeg` function simply isn't firing or working. The logs are returning an `rs = 1` which I believe means something is working in the `ffmpeg` function, but not sure why. Video (which will vary) is 1162 × 2066 and image is 500 × 500 pixels.

Comment: Try specifying the input & outputs of the filtergraph: `[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[vout]` and also explicitly map the output by adding `-map [vout]` (and `-map [0:a]` if there is audio) options right before the output file name

Comment: Okay, so ran `await FFmpegKit.executeAsync("-i $originalVideo -i $watermark -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[vout]' -map [vout] -map [0:a] $videoFile")`, however still nothing and same output. Does something need to go before the output file, `$videoFile`?

Comment: OK, You have `FFmpeg process exited with state COMPLETED and rs 1.` If flutter is like Python, a system call returning 1 means something did indeed go wrong.  But you aren't printing everything in the FFmpeg log `flutter: Last output ffmpeg version v4.5...`. You need to print the full log to find out what failed.

Comment: @kesh if you look below that line you will see the full output. However, I do not see any obvious errors in the output.

Comment: No we do not. There is that pesky `<…>` at the end. Modify your program to print every line of the FFmpeg log

Comment: @kesh okay getting closer! Updated the question. You can now see a new error pop up `flutter: File:: Protocol not found` and `flutter: Did you mean file:File:?`.

Comment: So flutter is converting its file object to string starting with `File:...`? You either need to remove the protocol (`File:`) or lower-case it to `file:` (I think the latter should work but do the former by trimming your string)

Comment: Okay, after a lot of playing, that was the root of the problem. It also seems that `FFmpeg` prefers paths to files, not actual Files in flutter. The command that eventually worked was `await FFmpegKit.executeAsync('-i $videoPath -i ${watermark.path} -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -y ${videoFile.path}')`. Thank you so much for your help! I will update the question above.